# Python sklearn and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelise training of classifiers from sklearn (gaussian mixture modell in this case) using multiprocessing and I get a lot worse classifiers in comparison with running them sequentially. Additionally each time after training the results are different as if the code was not thread safe. Can anyone explain me what is going on? Here is the code and at the end the thread function:

```
nrProc = 8
semaphore = Semaphore(nrProc)
m = Manager()
models = m.list()
modelsOut = m.list()
processes = []   

cnt = 0                
for event_label in data_positive:                        
    models.append(mixture.GMM(**classifier_params))  
    models.append(mixture.GMM(**classifier_params))

for event_label in data_positive:
    if classifier_method == 'gmm':                        
        processes.append(Process(target=trainProcess, args=(models[cnt], data_positive[event_label], semaphore, modelsOut)))
        cnt = cnt + 1                        
        processes.append(Process(target=trainProcess, args=(models[cnt], data_negative[event_label], semaphore, modelsOut)))
        cnt = cnt + 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown classifier method ["+classifier_method+"]")

for proc in processes:
    proc.start()

for proc in processes:
    proc.join()


cnt = 0                
for event_label in data_positive:
    model_container['models'][event_label] = {}
    model_container['models'][event_label]['positive'] = modelsOut[cnt]
    cnt = cnt + 1
    model_container['models'][event_label]['negative'] = modelsOut[cnt]
    cnt = cnt + 1

def trainProcess(model, data, semaphore, modelsOut):
    semaphore.acquire()    
    modelsOut.append(model.fit(data))
    semaphore.release()
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to use clone function from sklearn which does a deep copy of the estimator.